# How to remove the fade caused by BottomSheetDialog?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

How to make the BottomSheetDialog to slide up without fading the screen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.Layou‌​tParams.FLAG_DIM_BEH‌​IND);
```